# Software Firewall with 'log in' function

Tags: webserver, firewall, database-security

I need to secure a server with a firewall, that's simple :) But for certain users I would like to open certain other ports (for example direct access to the Database for SSRS report builders).

These users don't have static IP addresses, and so right now each time their address changes I have to Remote Desktop in, and add their new ip address to the 'allowed' section in Windows Firewall.

Anybody know of a software firewall solution that provides a web front end (on port 80?) that user's can log into to permit additional access?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I wrote a simple Lightswitch application that keeps track of user's IP addresses and a list of 'known' addresses. Every time people want access tot he database, they must log in there first, which then updates the firewall rules in windows firewall.